# Increment numbers in mapped array using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{location: {…}, distance: 0}
{location: {…}, distance: 0}
{location: {…}, distance: 0.37348441209694133}
{location: {…}, distance: 0}
{location: {…}, distance: 0.4229382782128456}
{location: {…}, distance: 0}
{location: {…}, distance: 0.006098292961396555}
{location: {…}, distance: 0}
{location: {…}, distance: 0.07885846317546494}]
```

I want to map a new array with the distance values incremented from the previous value. So in the example above the last distance value would be 0.88137944644665 because it was have added all the values by the time it iterated all objects.

In Ramda.js I've tried to add the previous distance value when I map the array but it doesn't work because it's undefined. I've also looked into reduce with no success. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this in Ramda.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much as I love Ramda you don't need it here:

```
arr.map(({ location, distance }) => ({ location, distance: distance + 1 }));
```

To break that down:

```
arr // your array of objects
  .map( // call to Array.prototype.map
    ({ location, distance }, i, arr) => // function params, destructures
      ({ location, distance: distance + 1 })); // return new object same loc, incremented distance
```

### EDIT

Since I missed the part about aggregation, use reduce instead:

```
arr.reduce((aggregate, { location, distance }, i) => {
  const dist = i ? aggregate[i - 1].distance : 0;
  aggregate.push({ location, distance: distance + dist });
  return aggregate;
}, []);
```

Comment: He wants the distance to aggregate, your solution only increments it by 1

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but asosnovsky is correct I want the distance aggregated.

Comment: @londonfed fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
const reducedData = data.reduce( (prev, val) => {
  prev.sum += val.distance
  prev.datas.push({
    ...val,
    distance: prev.sum
  })
  return prev;
}, {sum: 0, datas: []})
```

The `.reduce` loops on the data and merges each row into `prev`. The final output of this script is an object that looks like `{ sum: number , datas: [...]}`, `sum` in here is the total distance, and the `datas` will contain the array that you want.

See snapshot: [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking utilise Ramda functions here, [`R.scan`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#scan) can help. This function is very similar to `reduce` though instead of returning a single summarised value it will produce a list of every successive result.

```js
const distanceL = R.lensProp('distance')
const addDistance = R.compose(R.add, R.prop('distance'))
const fn = data =>
  R.scan(
    (acc, next) => R.over(distanceL, addDistance(acc), next),
    data[0],
    R.tail(data)
  )

console.log(fn([
  {location: {}, distance: 0},
  {location: {}, distance: 0},
  {location: {}, distance: 0.37348441209694133},
  {location: {}, distance: 0},
  {location: {}, distance: 0.4229382782128456},
  {location: {}, distance: 0},
  {location: {}, distance: 0.006098292961396555},
  {location: {}, distance: 0},
  {location: {}, distance: 0.07885846317546494}
]))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [`scan`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#scan):

```js
const {lift, scan, head, tail} = R

const xs = [
  {location: {id: 1}, distance: 0},
  {location: {id: 2}, distance: 0},
  {location: {id: 3}, distance: 0.37348441209694133},
  {location: {id: 4}, distance: 0},
  {location: {id: 5}, distance: 0.4229382782128456},
  {location: {id: 6}, distance: 0},
  {location: {id: 7}, distance: 0.006098292961396555},
  {location: {id: 8}, distance: 0},
  {location: {id: 9}, distance: 0.07885846317546494}
]

const accumDist = lift(scan((agg, x) => ({...x, distance: x.distance + agg.distance})))(head, tail)

console.log(accumDist(xs))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This won't work with an empty list.  If that's a concern, we could alter it by skipping `lift(...)(head, tail)` and just using the `scan` with an initial value, and then taking the `tail`.  But if that's not a concern, this code is clearer.

Comment: Oh, look, @ScottChristopher beat me to it.  This is enough different, that I'll keep it around anyway.